# WCF Data Service 5.0 (OData v3) and Web Api 2.2 (OData v4) in the same .net website project, how

Tags: asp.net-web-api, odata, wcf-data-services

Is it possible to use WCF Data Service 5.0 (OData v3) and Web Api 2.2 (OData v4) in the same .net website project.
How to add references for both without conflicting dlls

Answer (score 1):

The assemblies should not have conflicting. If you are using VS to develop, you can use nuget manager to add the references